# How to run the useQuery hook when the user session is authenticated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth, react-query

How to conditinally use the useQuery with React Query hook to fetch data when the session status is authenticated? I found an answer online that i have to use enabled flag, but it seems to not working. Initially, when the page is loaded, the session is undefined and the data returned from useQuery will also be undefined, only when the page rendered for the second time it will work.

I also got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
> at CashFlow.keepPreviousData [as queryFn] (index.tsx:62:14)
> at Object.fetchFn [as fn] (query.js:300:1)
> at run (retryer.js:95:1)
> at eval (retryer.js:149:1)

I'm using Next Auth for authentication and React Query for the data fetching in NextJS Pages directory
Here's my code:

```
    const {
    data: session,
    status,
    update,
} = useSession({
    required: true,
});
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        update();
    }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [update]);

const {
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    data: data,
    isFetching,
    isPreviousData,
    refetch,
} = useQuery(
    [
        "/api/cashflow",
        pageNumber,
        filterByYear,
        filterByMonth,
        transactionType,
    ],
    () =>
        getData(
            filterByYear,
            filterByMonth,
            transactionType,
            pageNumber.toString(),
            dataPerPage.toString(),
            session!.user.accessToken,
            session!.user.id
        ),
    {
        keepPreviousData: true,
        enabled: status === "authenticated",
    }
);
console.log(session);

useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
    setIsRefetch(false);
}, [isRefetch]);
```

Comment: Maybe you can set `enabled: false` and use the [react-query refetch](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery) function once you have the session of `useSession` setted.

Comment: @Klian That is working, thank you very much, you're really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that `enabled` does not work. Please have a look at the error.

It states that it can't read `user` (from `session`) since `session` is `undefined`. But you have promised the compiler that `session` won't be `undefined` by writing `session!`. Since this is not true, a runtime error is encountered.
Since the fetch function fails, `data` continues to be `undefined`.

To prevent `useQuery` from calling the query function before `session` is ready, add `session` to the `enabled` flag.

```js
useQuery(
    [
        "/api/cashflow",
        pageNumber,
        filterByYear,
        filterByMonth,
        transactionType,
    ],
    () =>
        getData(
            filterByYear,
            filterByMonth,
            transactionType,
            pageNumber.toString(),
            dataPerPage.toString(),
            session!.user.accessToken,
            session!.user.id
        ),
    {
        keepPreviousData: true,
        // disable until session is loaded
        enabled: status === "authenticated" && session !== undefined,
    }
);
```